# Find $P(Y>\frac{5}{4})$ when joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ is given

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study

The joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ is given as

$f(x,y)$ = $\frac{1}{2x^2y}$ , $1<x<∞$ and $\frac{1}{x}<y<x$

Then find $P(Y>\frac{5}{4})$

Since the limits of $Y$ have $X$ in them, I am not able to eliminate them.
First I calculated the pdf of $Y$ by integrating the joint pdf of domain of $X$, and then I have to integrate it over y, from $\frac{5}{4}$ to $x$ right? However, the solution is $\frac{2}{5}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the marginal probability density function $f_Y(y)$ of $Y$, you will need two cases based on the value of $y$. These cases due to the constraints on $y$ relative to $x$ in the given joint probability density function $f(x, y) = \frac{1}{2x^2y}$, where $1 < x < \infty$ and $\frac{1}{x} < y < x$. The appropriate bounds for integration depend on whether $y$ is less than 1 or greater than or equal to 1.

- Case 1: $y < 1$

  In this scenario, the condition $\frac{1}{x} < y < x$ combined with $y < 1$ suggests that $x$ must be greater than both $\frac{1}{y}$ and $\frac{1}{x}$, leading to $x > \frac{1}{y} > 1$. Since $\frac{1}{y} \ge 1$, the bounds for $x$ are from $\frac{1}{y}$ to $\infty$. Therefore, the marginal density function for $Y$ in this case is given by:
  $$
  f_Y(y) = \int_{\frac{1}{y}}^{\infty} f(x, y) \, dx, \quad \text{for } y < 1
  $$
- Case 2: $y \ge 1$

  For $y \ge 1$, the condition $1 \le y < x$ directly leads to the bounds for $x$ starting from $y$ to $\infty$. Thus, for values of $y$ in this range, the marginal density function is calculated as:
  $$
  f_Y(y) = \int_{y}^{\infty} f(x, y) \, dx, \quad \text{for } y \ge 1
  $$

Now, since you want $P(Y > \frac{5}{4})$, then you will be using the second case. That is, $$P\left(Y > \frac{5}{4} \right)= \int_{\frac{5}{4}}^\infty f_{Y}(y) \, dy$$

[image]

Comment: Understood, thanks. So while approaching questions like these, I always have to bring the domain of x in terms of y, and while doing that, I have to check when it exists

Comment: @AnweshanGoswami I would recommend that you make a graph. It will always help you to see the limit of integration

Comment: Alright. In a situation where I need to calculate something like P[Y<0.5], I would use the first marginal pdf. However, while calculating the actual probability, what should be the limits of y?

Comment: @AnweshanGoswami what was your $ f_{Y}(y)$ for $y <1$ ?

Comment: $f(y)=\frac{1}{2}$. For calculating $P(Y<0.5)$, I can subtract $P(Y>=0.5)$ from 1, but the integration is not defined in that range. We can also just set the range of Y from 0 to 0.5 (since it's value will never be negative), but this feels wrong for some reason

Answer (score 1):

This way seems somewhat simpler than the accepted answer:

Since $x>1,$ you have $1/x<5/4.$ Thus
\begin{align}
\Pr(Y>5/4) = {} & \iint\limits_{x\,>\,1\text{ and } 5/4\, <\, y\, <\, x} \frac{d(x,y)}{2x^2y} \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_{5/4}^\infty \left( \int_y^\infty \frac{dx}{2x^2y} \right) \, dy \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_{5/4}^\infty \frac{dy}{2y^2} = \frac25.
\end{align}
(Maybe most of the work is finding the bounds of integration.)